# fscanf считывает только одно слово

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    FILE* S1, * S2;
    printf("Введите имя файла для сортировки(без .txt): ");
    char sortname[256];
    gets(sortname);
    S1 = fopen(strcat(sortname, ".txt"), "r+");
    char info1[256];
    char info2[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        fscanf(S1, "%s [%s]", info1, info2);
        printf("%s\n", info1);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Например у меня в файле есть строка Klubnika Banan [Yabloko Apelsin]. При запуске программы в info1 записывается Klubnika, а в info2 записывается Yabloko.
Т.е при считывании пропускается все слова, кроме первого. Как это исправить? (мне нужно чтобы в info1 записывало Klubnika Banan, а в info2 Yabloko Apelsin)

Comment: Почитайте тут [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Поправил код. Вопрос, вроде, вполне понятен.

Comment: `scanf("%s` читает *одно* **слово**.

Comment: Есть какая-то возможность читать не одно слово, а несколько?

Comment: Вы сами написали такой формат -- `"%s [%s]"`. Он означает, пропустить пробелы, прочесть слово, пропустить все до `[`, прочесть слово. Если после первого слова первый непробельный символ будет отличен от `[`, то fscanf  вернет 1. / *`"Как это исправить"`* --  читать по строкам и разбирать текст самому

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменить строку в fscanf на `[a-zA-Z ]`. Она разберет строку содержащую символы от a до z, от A до Z и пробелы. Я еще добавил `%256` для указания максимального размера читаемой строки. Также добавил проверки конца файла, ошибок чтения и что считалось две строки.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    int numMatched = fscanf(S1, " %256[a-zA-Z ] [%256[a-zA-Z ]]", info1, info2);
    if (feof(S1) || ferror(S1))
      break;
    if (numMatched != 2)
      break; //некорректная строка.
    printf("%s, %s\n", info1, info2);
}
```

Comment: По крайней мере в Linux и при чтении с клавиатуры нескольких таких строк нужен формат с пробелом в начале строки, вот такой -- `" %256[a-zA-Z ] [%256[a-zA-Z ]]"`

Comment: В windows при чтении из файла последняя строка не читается, если нет пробела в начале строки. Поправил ответ.